# What access level should loggers be set to?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, access-levels

I'm using SLF4J with Log4J underneath. What access levels should I be setting my loggers to?

```
static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should use `private` access level, because every class should have its own copy of logger. Otherwise we can't tell which class really did the log record.

Comment: Makes sense, I ask because the SLF4J documentation left off the access modifier, so I didn't know if there were situations where you needed other classes to access the logger.

Comment: Classes internal to the logging system may need to, but they maintain their own references anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I always set them to private.  Is there any reason any other class would need access to this logger?

Comment: I've seen some people that will design superclasses in a way that a logger is exposed to the child classes

Comment: I've actually done that Matt, protected access makes sense to me in that case.

Comment: @matt b: I've never seen that before.  I'll have to try it out to see what it does to the log record.

Comment: `protected`? that's hideous. `protected static` is always a mistake.

Comment: You'll see that sometimes in frameworks like Spring, where you might extend one of their controllers or DaoSupport classes. The loggers will be declared as protected final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()), so that they'll be the runtime class's type.

Comment: @matt b, yeah that is exactly what I was doing. For protected loggers I don't use static.